# Efficient way to display multiple arrays of data into single tableview section

Tags: ios, swift

I have a data model as below:

```
class Model {
var field1 = Data()
var field2 = Data()
var field3 = [Data]()
var field4 = [Data]()
}
var model = Model() // Provide data here
```

The Model will be fetched and parsed from API, i use another class Data as a sub-model to form Model. And I need to display the Model object into a single table view section in the order:

> field1 -> field2 -> [field3] -> [field4]

What i am planning to do is as below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return model.count
```

}

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StatusCell") as! StatusCell
switch indexPath.row {
  case 0:
    // Do something with field1
  case 1:
    // Do something with field2
  case 2...(2 + field3.count):
    // Do something with field3
  case (2 + field3.count)...(2 + field3.count + field4.count)
    // Do something with field4
return cell
}
```

As my point, it's a lot inefficient, since every time cellForRowAt is called, it has to calculate the array size again and again, but I have to check the array to display them in the pre-defined order above. However, that is the only way currently in my mind.

I would like to improve the code for better efficiency, may be the way the data should be stored in the model(instead of an array or something like that...) or how to populate data properly into the table view. Please help to point me out where should the code be improved and how.

Thanks

Comment: what is in "Data" class (Type of data)

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way is to you can use tableView Section but as you describe that you want to populate all the data fields in single section for this simply don't implement the titlefroHeader delegate or pass the empty string in this delegate you can see that the tableview populate like in single section.

```
 override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return numberOfFields
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0
    {
        return [field1 count]
    }
    else
    {
        return [otherfield count]
    }
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
  if indexPath.section == 0
    {
        cell.textLabel?.text = field1 .object(at: indexPath.row)
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel?.text = otherfield .object(at: indexPath.row)
    }// assuming fileds array containing string
    return cell
}//pass empty string in this delegate or dont implement it, or if you want to display the first header text the pass in other empty string 
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
     if section == 0
    return "section"
    else 
      return ""
}
```

}

Please feel free if you need to discuss anything else

Comment: That's a good trick. I really appreciate if you could show me more ways to improve this! I am thinking of merging these data field into another single array for the purpose of populating them into tableView, but it has to create additional memory

Answer (score 0):

The best option for you here is to use table view sections for every field property, but if you wish to use only 1 section, you can simply combine your data:

```
class Model {
     var field1 = Data()
     var field2 = Data()
     var field3 = [Data]()
     var field4 = [Data]()

     func getAllFields() -> [Data] {
          return [field1, field2] + field3 + field4
     }
}

let allModelFields = model.getAllFields()    

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
     return allModelFields.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StatusCell") as! StatusCell
     let fieldItem = allModelFields[indexPath.row]
     // TODO: Configure your cell with current field item
     return cell
}
```

Updated:
Not is the best solution, but should work for your specific kind of request, but I will rather recommend you to change your model and use 1 array if your logic allows this or simply use table view sections.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StatusCell") as! StatusCell
let row = indexPath.row
switch row {
  case 0, 1:
    // Do something with field1 or field2
  default:
    let field3count = model.field3.count
    if row - 1 <= field3count {
       let field3item = model.field3[row - 2]
       //Do something with field3item
    } else {
       let field4item = model.field4[row - 2 - field3count]
       //Do something with field4item
    }
return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if we combine array together, we will duplicate data and waste memory.

Comment: @TuyenVoQuang I've updated my answer for you, but be aware that this is not a clean solution. Feel free to ask if something is not clear for you

Comment: Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

I know it too late but new users like me who will find the question will get this answer. I have three arrays and need to show three heading on every array. here is my code and result image, hope it will help others.

```
extension TripViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let count = array1.count + array2.count + array3.count + 3
    return count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
   
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell?.textLabel?.textColor = .red
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "Heading 1"
    } else if indexPath.row + 1 <= array1.count + 1 {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = array1[indexPath.row - 1]
        
    } else if indexPath.row == array1.count + 1 {
        cell?.textLabel?.textColor = .red
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "Heading 2"
        
    } else if indexPath.row <= array2.count + array1.count + 1 {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = array2[indexPath.row - array1.count - 2]
        
    } else if indexPath.row == array1.count + array2.count + 2 {
        cell?.textLabel?.textColor = .red
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "Heading 3"
        
    } else if indexPath.row <= array1.count + array2.count + array3.count + 3 {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = array3[indexPath.row - array1.count - array2.count - 3]
    }
    return cell!
}
}
```

[image: Here is result]